# I'm trying to write a program which outputs "n" (input) fibonacci numbers

Tags: c++, codeblocks, fibonacci

I am struggling with my program. It should output n Fibonacci numbers, each on a new line. If the Fibonacci number exceeds the range of an `unsigned int` you should just exit the program. Moreover, you should print on a new line how many Fibonaccis of "n" are displayed.

Here is the code so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  unsigned int n;

  cout << "Please enter the amount of fibonaccis you would like to compute:  " << endl;
  cin >> n;

  unsigned int next=1;
  unsigned int current=0;
  unsigned int c = current;
  unsigned int temp;
  unsigned int counter=1;

  //This bool returns true as soon as an overflow occurs
  bool overflow; 

 /*This bool checks, whether the newly computed 
    number is bigger than the previous number 
   (which may not be the case if an overflow occurs)*/

  bool nextBigger; 



  /*Somehow, I could only handle the first
    inputs by using "bruteforce".
    If I tried to combine it with the "main loop",
    it got all messy. */

  if(n==0)
  {
    std::cout << "0" << " of " << n << endl;
  }

  else if(n==1)
  {
     std::cout << "0" << endl << "1 of " << n << endl;
  }

  else if(n==2)
  {
     std::cout << "0" << endl << "1" << endl << "2 of " << n << endl;
  }

  else
  {   /* This for-loop increases (at least it should) a counter
         by one for each computation of a valid fibonacci number*/

      for(counter=1;counter<n;++counter)
      {

         overflow = (c > (std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()-temp));

         if(!overflow && nextBigger)
         {
            cout << next << endl;

         }

         else
        {
           break; //If overflow or next number < previous number, exit program
        }

        temp = next; //temp is storage variable for next
        c = current; //storage variable for current
        next += current; //next is being altered: it becomes the new fibonacci number
        current = temp; //current gets value of temp( value of next before being altered)
   }

  nextBigger = (next > current);

  cout << counter << " of " << n << endl; //Output of how many fibonaccis were computed
}

  return 0;
}
```

So here is the thing. I programmed it in CodeBlocks, where it worked perfectly. But then I tried to upload it in Codeboard (as an assignment). In Codeboard it suddenly didn't work at all. Maybe it has to do with the different compilers, but I really have no clue how I could fix this issue. So I am quite puzzled and I'd be very thankful for any hints, ideas, corrections or inspirations.

(I am a beginner, so I hope the code is understandable and readable. I am open for suggested improvements.)

Comment: Do you get an error message? Wrong result? Or what else does not work exactly?

Comment: You're going to have to give us more than [‘*didn't work*’](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. So when I try to run it with "codeboard" it only outputs "0" and on a new line "1 of 49". So I thought the for-loop is not being executed. And as I mentioned in "codeblocks" it did work out. For instance, if you give the input "49" it outputs 48 Fibonaccis and tells the user that "48 of 49" are displayed. I don't get any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it seems the body of the if statement

```
if(!overflow && nextBigger)
    {
       cout << next << endl;
    }
```

is never executed. Maybe print the values for overflow and nextBigger on each loop iteration so you can debug what's happening.